# Mongoose - Multiple models for 1 schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose v5.2.17.
I was wondering is it possible to have multiple models map to the 1 schema.
For example - I have the following model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const _ = require('lodash');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email',
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
  },  
  isTrialUser: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  isAdminUser: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  }
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;
  const userObject = user.toObject();

  return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email', 'isTrialUser']);
};


UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;

  if (user.isModified('password')) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (hashErr, hash) => {
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = { User, UserSchema };
```

Is it possible for me to create another AdminModel where admin specific methods can live?
I also want to return all data from the toJSON method from the AdminModel.

Please let me know if this is possible or if there is a better way to perform such a task

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to inherit the UserModel in an AdminModel and `decorate` that one with extra methods etc. For that you can use `util.inherits` (or the so called Mongoose discriminators) like so:

```
function BaseSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    name: String,
    createdAt: Date
  });
}
util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);

var UserSchema = new BaseSchema();
var AdminSchema = new BaseSchema({ department: String });
```

You can read more about it in [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator).

There is also a good article on the [mongoose discriminators here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/07/24/guide-to-mongoose-discriminators)